# Solve the given differential equation: $L\frac{di}{dt} + Ri = E$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the given DE knowing that L, R, and E are constants. I am using the method of finding the integrating factor but when I find $Mi$ and $Nt$ I encounter a problem. Where did I go wrong?

$$
Mi = \frac{R^2t}{L^2} 
$$
$$
Nt = \frac{R}{L}
$$

For this method to work, these need to be equal. What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 1):

Solve the homogeneous eq(that is, put E=0)
And find the special solution of the equation. In this case i=E/R is the special solution. By the linearity of the diff. eq, summing two solutions will give you the complete solution of the equation

Comment: Why is it an option to make E=0? And why is i=E/R the special solution?

Comment: It isn't an option as such.  Mathcho's hint is the standard approach: Decompose $i(t) = i_h(t)+i_0(t)$, where $i_h(t)$ is a solution to the so-called homogeneous equation $L\frac{di}{dt}+Ri = 0$, and $i_0(t)$ is a more *ad hoc* solution to the original equation that can often be obtained more easily.  We use the exponential function's property that its derivative is a constant multiple of itself to obtain $i_h(t)$, and the fact that $E$ is a constant to easily obtain $i_0(t) = E/R$.  Finally, because differentiation is a linear operator, we can combine the parts together.

Comment: By linear operator, I mean simply that $\frac{d}{dt} ki = k\frac{di}{dt}$, where $k$ is a constant, and $\frac{d}{dt}(i+j) = \frac{di}{dt}+\frac{dj}{dt}$, where $i$ and $j$ are functions of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Or substitute $j = Ri-E$ to turn the equation into
$$
\frac LR \frac{dj}{dt} = -j \\
j = k e^{-\frac RL t}
$$
So the solution is 
$$
i = \frac{j+E}{R} = C e^{-\frac RL t} + \frac{E}{R}
$$
for arbitary constant $C$ (which is to related to the arbitrary constant $k$ by $C=k/R$).